# Graphql: read SDL directive from type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to get directives from a type.

Part of schema:

```
directive @translates(
    type: String
) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION


type DocumentTranslated @translates(type: Document) {
...
}
```

Reading schema:

```
info.schema.getTypeMap()['DocumentTranslated'].astNode
```

Result:

```
{ kind: 'ObjectTypeDefinition',
  description: undefined,
  name:
   { kind: 'Name',
     value: 'DocumentTranslated',
     loc: { start: 8893, end: 8911 } },
  interfaces: [],
  directives: [],
  fields:
```

I don't get, why directives are not present in AST? How can I read type directives?